Why can't rust code process borrow checking at compile time?
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::VecDeque;

struct TextEditor {
    content: String,
    history: RefCell<VecDeque<String>>,
}

impl TextEditor {
    fn new(initial_content: &str) -> TextEditor {
        TextEditor {
            content: initial_content.to_string(),
            history: RefCell::new(VecDeque::new()),
        }
    }

    fn edit(&mut self, new_content: &str) {
        self.history.borrow_mut().push_front(self.content.clone());
        self.content = new_content.to_string();
    }

    fn undo(&mut self) -> Result<(), String> {
        let mut history_borrow = self.history.borrow_mut();
        if let Some(previous_content) = history_borrow.pop_front() {
            self.content = previous_content;
            self.history.borrow(); // panic
            Ok(())
        } else {
            Err("No previous history available.".to_string())
        }
    }

    fn print_content(&self) {
        println!("Current content: {}", self.content);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut editor = TextEditor::new("Initial content");

    editor.edit("First change");
    editor.print_content();

    editor.edit("Second change");
    editor.print_content();

    if editor.undo().is_ok() {
        editor.print_content();
    }

    editor.history.borrow();
}


The following Rust code triggers panic, why is that?
After simplifying the logic a bit while coding and debugging it, I realized that it went panic because of borrowing issues, but why it didn't do borrow checking at compile time but went panic?

You're using a RefCell, so you're asking rust to borrow check at run time.    If you want to borrow check at compile time, don't use the RefCell.

RefCell is a smart-pointers, that enforces borrow checker dynamically (at runtime) and Not in compile time.
you should read the docs

... However, there are situations where this rule (it's talking about the compile time borrow checker) is not flexible enough. Sometimes it is required to have multiple references to an object and yet mutate it. Shareable mutable containers exist to permit mutability in a controlled manner, even in the presence of aliasing. Cell<T>, RefCell<T>, and OnceCell<T> allow doing this in a single-threaded way ...

